# GetElementById and A tags

Tags: target, getelementbyid

Getting error on this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
    oAllKits = myNode.getElementById('node' + i).getElementsByTagName('a');
}
```

I have a series of IDs on the html document called: node1, node2,... node18. I am trying to target the A tags on these IDs since these A tags are the only elements inside these ids. The console is giving me this message: # has no method 'getElementById'.
I am doing a for loop because I want the variable oAllKits to hold an all those A tags inside the Ids. Thank you advance for your help.

Comment: Show us more of your code, if it's complaining about `getELementById` the issue might be where you set `myNode`. It might be worth getting JSFiddle going so we can see more of the code, such as your HTML that the Javascript is interacting with.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done easily. Find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UhT2W/)

or you can see the code

```
var avar = document.getElementById('div');
var bvar = div.getElementsByTagName('a');
var cvar = children.length;
for (var i=0;i < len;i++) {
    document.getElementById('aclass').innerHTML +='<br> ' + children[i].href;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementById exists on the document.  There should be only 1 of any particular ID so the selector is fast.

```
var div = document.getElementById('id1');
var children = div.getElementsByTagName('a');
var len = children.length;
for (var i=0;i < len;i++) {
        document.getElementById('found').innerHTML += '<br> ' + children[i].href;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UhT2W/1/

Comment: Thank you for answering. I had it set like you have above and it got all the A tags, I mean all of them, even the ones I don't want. I just want the A tags that are on the divs that starts with "node". I notice that my error was caused because the method getElementById is used for DOM element "documnet" and I was using it on a DOM node. That fixed part of it. I changed myNode to document. But now when I console.log(oAllKits) it returns 0.